# How to search particular app on TIZEN STORE by the help of TIZEN PROGRAMMING?

Tags: tizen, tizen-native-app

I used

```
 app_control_h app_control;
        app_control_create(&app_control);
        app_control_set_operation(app_control, APP_CONTROL_OPERATION_DEFAULT);
        app_control_set_app_id(app_control, "com.dumadugames.FootballKickFlick");

        if (app_control_(app_control, NULL,NULL) == APP_CONTROL_ERROR_NONE)
        {
            //code for successfull load web site

        }
        else
        {
            //Code for log error.
        }

        app_control_destroy(app_control);
```

so it's  NOT open PARTICULAR APP.
  i also previlize in menifest.

I am new in TIZEN so please help me.what till i have done i am making one basicui and one app for widget but i need to integrate both in one so how i will do give some idea and if you have basics sample.thanks a lot in advance .
sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look in [this link](https://developer.tizen.org/sites/default/files/documentation/4_tizen_native_app_dev_tizen_studio.pdf). You'll find a very good documentation on developing widget apps and integrating widget app with UI app here.

Comment: Hi i have some more problem please see @Shaswati Saha.

Comment: Create a new thread and re-edit it to the previous so that it can keep the objective of developer forum.

Comment: hi Shawati Saha i am new in tizen please help me out. iam strugling for retrive installed apps list please help me thanks.